# React native maps mapPadding not working

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I'm using `fitToSuppliedMarkers()` for my markers and need to add some padding to my map. I have tried to implement [this solution](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/pull/1750) with no luck. I can't use `fitToCoordinates()` because I need to create the markers in `componentDidMount` which that method doesn't support.

My code:

```
<MapView onMapReady={() => this.mapRef.map.setNativeProps({ padding: 100 })}></MapView>
```

This code yields "setNativeProps is not a function".
I have also tried using the `mapPadding` property that exists in the [docs](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md) with no luck:

```
<MapView mapPadding={{top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20}}></MapView>
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe there is an issue with the android implementation of react-native-maps. I am not sure but it seems to be an issue with the px to dp conversion. Try this:

```
const padding = Platform.OS === 'android' 
                   ? PixelRatio.getPixelSizeForLayoutSize(20) 
                   : 20;

const mapPadding = {top: padding, right: padding, bottom: padding, left: padding};
```

If it doesn't work try setting padding to 200 and see if there is any difference.

**Edit:** 
This is the exact code i am using successfully:

```
const iosEdgePadding = { top: 100, right: 50, bottom: 300, left: 50 };

const androidEdgePadding = {
    top: PixelRatio.getPixelSizeForLayoutSize(iosEdgePadding.top),
    right: PixelRatio.getPixelSizeForLayoutSize(iosEdgePadding.right),
    bottom: PixelRatio.getPixelSizeForLayoutSize(iosEdgePadding.bottom),
    left: PixelRatio.getPixelSizeForLayoutSize(iosEdgePadding.left),
}

const edgePadding = (Platform.OS === 'android') ? androidEdgePadding : iosEdgePadding;

this.refs.map.fitToCoordinates([coordinate1, coordinate2], { edgePadding, animated: true })
```

Comment: Thanks I tried your solution but It didn't work unfortunately. No padding was being applied.

Comment: Added some code that i use and have got to work. Make sure you have the latest version of react-native-maps installed as well :)

Comment: I can't use fitToCoordinates because my markers is coming from a request I need to do in componentDidMount which that method do not support.

Answer (score 0):

mapPadding={{ top: 100, right: 100, bottom: 100, left: 100 }}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is weird and I don't know why it works but this worked for me on android perfectly. Without Platform.select it doesn't work. Hope this helps anyone!

```js
const iosEdgePadding = {
    bottom: height / bottomPadding,
    left: width / 5,
    right: width / 5,
    top: 100,
  };

  const edgePadding = Platform.select({
    ios: iosEdgePadding,
    android: iosEdgePadding,
  });

  mapView.fitToCoordinates(radiusBoundaries, {
    edgePadding,
    animated: true,
  });
```